# command usage and meaning

Tags: command-line, drivers, documentation

I immediately while i was reading a plasmapy document, preformed

(plasma_store -m 1000000000 -s /tmp/plasma) command and now I don't know

what exactly it do on my system. Exactualy I read the pattern of command

but I think it just tell the system assigned 1GB space to plasmapy on linux.

what do you understand from this command?

the system reaction to assigned command was:

(Allowing the Plasma store to use up to 1GB of memory.
Starting object store with directory /dev/shm and huge page support disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to start plasma_store limiting the used memory to 1GB. As soon as you stop the command, the memory should be freed.

---

> The `-m` flag specifies the size of the store in bytes, and the `-s` flag
>   specifies the socket that the store will listen at. Thus, the above
>   command allows the Plasma store to use up to 1GB of memory, and sets
>   the socket to `/tmp/plasma`.

Source: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/plasma.html